# :app:mergeDebugResourses error after trying to import a Sketchware project to Android Studio

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So, I'm on a project with my workouts and I actually don't know about programming very well (I do this just for hobby, since I work in a Hospital Pharmacy). I was trying to create a notification app that reports to all devices with it when one of the hospital sector is in trouble.

By using Sketchware I was able to do pretty much, but after that I perceived that to be able to use Cloud Messaging for push notifications from Firebase I would need a better Google-Services that Sketchware gives. So after a while I've been able to convert it, but I just don't know what went wrong. I tried updating Gradle, downgrading Gradle, tried some solutions that I found here, like changing the "compile" to "implementation" and that helped a little, but did not mitigate all of the errors. Now I'm Stuck...

Here is my build.gradle from the project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files}


allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

}

This is the app folder build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 28
    }
android {
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    }
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.newproject2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.7"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything syncs fine, but when I try to build it it gives me this error:

```
> org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: ...
```

EDIT: I changed gradle to 3.3.2 and it looks like the problem is minor, but I still have problems:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.getXmlString(PositionXmlParser.java:288)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.getXmlString(PositionXmlParser.java:199)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:137)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:92)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:101)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser2.parseDocument(ValueResourceParser2.java:212)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser2.parseFile(ValueResourceParser2.java:91)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:534)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.parseFolder(ResourceSet.java:468)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.readSourceFolder(ResourceSet.java:274)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:246)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:55)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:242)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please write your post entirely in English

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that I were on a english website in the middle of the question lol